# How to use @mui/material 5 in shadow dom without losing styles?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

There are answers about using StylesProvider in @mui/styles, however it's deprecated in v5, what should we do in v5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand properly, your issue is that you render a React app in shadow dom, however styles generated by MUI are outside the shadow dom, in the main document?

If yes, here's my approach:

```
// imports
import createCache from "@emotion/cache";

// code
// I assume you have created shadow root already 
const headElement = document.createElement("head");
const rootElement = document.createElement("div");

shadow.appendChild(headElement); // used like document.head (styles only)
shadow.appendChild(rootElement); // used like document.body (UI)

const stylesCache = createCache({
  key: "your-key", // <style data-emotion="your-key">...
  container: headElement,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This has just helped me: The MUI Shadow DOM doc has a fairly new chapter about this (seeing from the git repo issue from June) https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/shadow-dom/ which then has a helpful example codesandbox of how to implement it https://codesandbox.io/s/shadow-dom-rki9k5?from-embed

All the code there is important, so copying it here is probably useless, but essentially, to keep the MUI themes through the shadowDOM, it requires some base elements from MUI themes and a CacheProvider. Might need to upgrade your react-dom to follow this example. Since you want to use your existing theme you could then merge the shadowTheme with your own theme:

```
theme = createTheme(shadowTheme, yourTheme);
```